# Assigning an DateTime interval to a DateTime Event

Tags: r, date, intervals, lubridate

I have a table of >1M individual DateTime detection intervals (i.e. an individual was continuously detected during this time) and a table DateTime Intervals which represent when a gate was closed.  The individual detections are classified as being "IN" or "OUT"

Using %within% I've been able to determine whether a detection falls within ANY of the intervals.

However, I'd like to do something a bit different. For each gate closed interval I'd like to know how many individuals were detected outside and how many inside.  I believe that the easiest way this can be done is by assigning each detection event to a gate period, but I can't figure out how that function would be written without extremely messy nested ifelse statements.

expected output (not real data):

```
  Tag     site  species      StartDateTime_UTC   EndDateTime_UTC     interval Location
   <fct>   <fct> <chr>        <dttm>              <dttm>                 <dbl> <chr>   
 1 5004.24 IC1   Striped Bass 2014-09-29 22:40:40 2014-09-29 22:46:35        1 IN      
 2 5004.24 IC1   Striped Bass 2014-09-29 22:49:15 2014-09-29 22:50:05        1 IN      
 3 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-01 23:01:12 2014-10-01 23:11:23        2 IN      
 4 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-01 23:16:18 2014-10-02 00:13:17        2 IN      
 5 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 00:15:47 2014-10-02 00:30:08        2 IN      
 6 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 00:33:12 2014-10-02 01:10:21        2 IN      
 7 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 01:13:01 2014-10-02 01:20:12        2 IN      
 8 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 04:14:15 2014-10-02 04:21:11        2 IN      
 9 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 04:23:31 2014-10-02 04:26:06       NA IN      
10 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 04:28:21 2014-10-02 04:32:16       NA IN      
11 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 22:00:06 2014-10-02 22:44:08       NA IN      
12 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 22:46:58 2014-10-02 23:08:21        5 IN      
13 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 23:10:36 2014-10-03 00:26:00        5 IN      
14 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 00:28:55 2014-10-03 00:51:35        5 IN      
15 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 00:55:06 2014-10-03 01:08:01        5 IN      
16 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 01:10:36 2014-10-03 01:17:21        6 IN      
17 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 01:20:41 2014-10-03 01:21:01        6 IN      
18 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 01:30:41 2014-10-03 01:31:07        6 IN      
19 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 01:35:02 2014-10-03 01:38:12        7 IN      
20 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 01:42:02 2014-10-03 01:58:18        7 IN
```

Some detections may not occur when the gates are closed thus "NA" is valid

Are there some better options?

dput:

Detections:

```
structure(list(Tag = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("5004.24", 
"5010.04", "5011.03", "5011.07", "5017.06", "5025.22", "5025.26", 
"5032.24", "5038.04", "5039.03", "5039.07", "5045", "5053.26", 
"5067.07", "5073.06", "5074.16", "5088.11", "5094.04", "5101.06", 
"5116.24", "5123.03", "5123.07", "5150.04", "5157.06", "5165.22", 
"5172.24", "5179.03", "5179.07", "5186.16", "5200.11", "5206.31", 
"5214.16", "5228.24", "5235", "5242.16", "5249", "5256.24", "5263.07", 
"5270.16", "5284.11", "5290.31", "5298.16", "5312.11", "5318.04", 
"5326.16", "5340.11", "5347.07", "5361.26", "5368.24", "5374.04", 
"5375.03", "5375.07", "5381.06", "5402.31", "5403.07", "5431.07", 
"5438.16", "5445.26", "5465.06", "5480.24", "5487.03", "5487.07", 
"5493.06", "5501.22", "5514.31", "5536.11", "5542.31", "5550.16", 
"5557.22", "5564.24", "5570.04", "5571.03", "5571.07", "5577", 
"5585.26", "5592.11", "5599.15", "5605.06", "5620.11", "5626.31", 
"5627.15", "5641.22", "5641.26", "5648.11", "5654.31", "5662.16", 
"5676.24", "5682.04", "5683.03", "5683.07", "5690.16", "5697.22", 
"5697.26", "5704.11", "5710.04", "5717.06", "5732.11", "5738.31", 
"5739.15", "5744.11", "5746.16", "5753", "5760.24", "5766.31", 
"5767.01", "5774.16", "5781.22", "5788.11", "5794.31", "5802.16", 
"5816.11", "5822.04", "5823.15", "5829.06", "5837.26", "5844.24", 
"5851.03", "5851.07", "5857.06", "5858.16", "5865.22", "5872.24", 
"5878.31", "5879.03", "5879.07", "5886.16", "5893.22", "5900.24", 
"5906.31", "5907.01", "5914.16", "5921.22", "5928.24", "5934.31", 
"5935.01", "5949.26", "5956.24", "5990.31", "5991.07", "5998.16", 
"6012.24", "6018.04", "6019.03", "6019.07", "6025.06", "6033.26", 
"6040.24", "6046.04", "6047.01", "6053", "6061", "6068.24", "6075.01", 
"6096.11", "6102.31", "6103.07", "6124.11", "6130.31", "6131.15", 
"6145.26", "6158.04", "6159.07", "6165.06", "6173.22", "6180.11", 
"6186.31", "6187.15", "6201.22", "6208.24", "6214.04", "6215.01", 
"6221.06", "6236.11", "6242.31", "6264.11", "6270.04", "6277.06", 
"6285.26", "6292.24", "6298.04", "6299.03", "6299.07", "6305.06", 
"6320.11", "6326.31", "6327.15", "6341.26", "6348.11", "6355.15", 
"6361.06", "6376.11", "6382.04", "6383.15", "6389.06", "6404.24", 
"6410.31", "6411.03", "6411.07", "6425.22", "6425.26", "6432.24", 
"6438.31", "6439.03", "6460.11", "6474.16", "6488.11", "6494.04", 
"6495.15", "6501.06", "6502.16", "6509.22", "6516.24", "6523.01", 
"6529.06", "6537.26", "6544.24", "6550.31", "6551.03", "6551.07", 
"6558.16", "6572.24", "6578.31", "6579.03", "6579.07", "6600.24", 
"6606.31", "6607.03", "6607.07", "6614.16", "6621.26", "6628.11", 
"6634.31", "6635.15", "6649.26", "6656.24", "6662.31", "6663.03", 
"6663.07", "6670.16", "6684.11", "6690.31", "6691.15", "6698.16", 
"6705.22", "6712.24", "6718.31", "6719.07", "6746.04", "6747.07", 
"6753.06", "6768.24", "6775.01", "6796.24", "6803.03", "6803.07", 
"6809.06", "6824.24", "6831.03", "6838.16", "6845", "6852.24", 
"6858.04", "6859.03", "6859.07", "6873.26", "6886.04", "6887.07", 
"6893.06", "6894.16", "6901.22", "6915.07", "6921.06", "6936.11", 
"6942.04", "6943.15", "6949.06", "6964.11", "6970.04", "6971.15", 
"6977.06", "6992.11", "6998.04", "6999.15", "7005.06", "7006.16", 
"7020.24", "7026.31", "7027.03", "7027.07", "7034.16", "7041.22", 
"7048.24", "7054.31", "7055.01", "7062.16", "7076.24", "7082.31", 
"7083.01", "7090.16", "7097", "7104.24", "7111.01", "7118.16", 
"7132.11", "7153.22", "7167.07", "7173.06", "7188.11", "7194.31", 
"7195.15", "7216.24", "7222.31", "7223.03", "7223.07", "7244.24", 
"7250.31", "7251.03", "7251.07", "7278.04", "7285.06", "7286.16", 
"7300.11", "7306.31", "7321.26", "7328.24", "7334.31", "7335.01", 
"7356.24", "7363", "7369.06", "7370.16", "7377.26", "7384.11", 
"7390.04", "7391.15", "7397.06", "7398.16", "7412.24", "7418.31", 
"7419.07", "7426.16", "7440.24", "7447.01", "7453.06", "7454.16", 
"7468.24", "7481.06", "7489", "7496.24", "7502.04", "7503.07", 
"7509", "7510.16", "7517.22", "7517.26", "7524.24", "7530.04", 
"7531.03", "7531.07", "7537.06", "7552.24", "7558.31", "7559.03", 
"7559.07", "7580.11", "7587.15", "7601.26", "7615.07", "7621.06", 
"7622.16", "7629.26", "7636.11", "7664.11", "7678.16", "7699.07", 
"7705.06", "7713.22", "7720.24", "7727.03", "7727.07", "7733.06", 
"7734.16", "7755.07", "7761.06", "7769.22", "7769.26", "7776.24", 
"7782.04", "7783.03", "7783.07", "7789.06", "7810.31", "7811.07", 
"7832.11", "7838.31", "7839.15", "7846.16", "7860.24", "7874.16", 
"7888.24", "7894.31", "7895.01", "7909.22", "7909.26", "7916.24", 
"7923", "7937", "7944.11", "7958.16", "7972.11", "7978.31", "7979.15", 
"8000.11", "8006.31", "8007.15", "8028.24", "8035.01", "8042.16", 
"8056.24", "8063.03", "8063.07", "8070.16", "8084.11", "8098.16", 
"8105.22", "8112.24", "8118.31", "8119.01", "8133.26", "8140.24", 
"8146.04", "8147.03", "8147.07", "8153.06", "8154.16", "8168.11", 
"8174.31", "8182.16", "8196.24", "8202.31", "8203.03", "8203.07", 
"8217.26", "8224.24", "8231.03", "8231.07", "8258.31", "8273.22", 
"8280.11", "8286.31", "8301.22", "8308.24", "8314.31", "8315.07", 
"8336.11", "8343.15", "8349.06", "8350.16", "8364.24", "8370.31", 
"8371.07", "8385", "8392.24", "8398.31", "8399.03", "8399.07", 
"8420.11", "8426.31", "8427.15", "8448.11", "8455.15", "8462.16", 
"8476.24", "8483.03", "8483.07", "8489.06", "8504.24", "8510.04", 
"8511.03", "8511.07", "8517.06", "8518.16", "8532.24", "8538.04", 
"8539.03", "8539.07", "8560.24", "8566.31", "8567.03", "8567.07", 
"8581.22", "8595.07", "8601.06", "8616.11", "8629.06", "8630.16", 
"8637.26", "8644.11", "8651.15", "8672.24", "8678.31", "8679.07", 
"8686.16", "8700.11", "8706.04", "8707.15", "8713.06", "8714.16", 
"8735.07", "8741.06", "8742.16", "8756.11", "8762.04", "8777.22", 
"8777.26", "8784.24", "8790.31", "8791.03", "8791.07", "8798.16", 
"8812.24", "8818.31", "8819.03", "8819.07", "8833.22", "8846.31", 
"8874.31", "8875.07", "8882.16", "8896.11", "8902.31", "8910.16", 
"8924.11", "8937.06", "8938.16", "8952.11", "8958.04", "8959.15", 
"8965.06", "8980.24", "8986.31", "8987.03", "8987.07", "8994.16", 
"9008.24", "9014.31", "9015.01", "9043.01", "9049.06", "9057.22", 
"9064.24", "9070.04", "9071.01", "9077.06", "9078.16", "9085.22", 
"9092.11", "9105.06", "9113.26", "9120.24", "9127.03", "9127.07", 
"9134.16", "9141.26", "9154.31", "9155.03", "9155.07", "9169.22", 
"9176.11", "9189.06", "9197", "9210.31", "9211.07", "9225", "9232.24", 
"9238.31", "9239.01", "9246.16", "9260.24", "9266.31", "9288.11", 
"9294.04", "9301.06", "9302.16", "9309.26", "9316.24", "9323.03", 
"9323.07", "9344.24", "9351.03", "9351.07", "9372.24", "9378.31", 
"9386.16", "9393.26", "9400.24", "9407.03", "9407.07", "9428.24", 
"9434.31", "9435.03", "9435.07", "9456.11", "9462.31", "9463.15", 
"9470.16", "9477.22", "9490.04", "9491.07", "9497.06", "9512.11", 
"9518.04", "9519.15", "9525.06", "9540.24", "9547.03", "9547.07", 
"9568.24", "9574.31", "9575.01", "9596.11", "9603.07", "9610.16", 
"9624.11", "9631.15", "9637.06", "9652.24", "9658.04", "9659.03", 
"9659.07", "9665.06", "9673.26", "9680.11", "9686.31", "9708.24", 
"9714.31", "9715.01", "9729.26", "9736.24", "9742.04", "9743.03", 
"9743.07", "9757.26", "9764.24", "9770.31", "9771.07", "9785.22", 
"9785.26", "9792.24", "9798.31", "9813.22", "9820.24", "9826.04", 
"9827.03", "9827.07", "9833.06", "9841.22", "9848.11", "9855.15", 
"9862.16", "9869.26", "9876.24", "9882.31", "9890.16", "9897.26", 
"9904.24", "9911.07", "9917.06", "9939.03", "9939.07", "9967.07", 
"9973.06", "9988.24", "9995.01"), class = "factor"), Start.Time = c("9/29/2014 10:40:40 PM", 
"9/29/2014 10:49:15 PM", "10/1/2014 11:01:12 PM", "10/1/2014 11:16:18 PM", 
"10/2/2014 12:15:47 AM", "10/2/2014 12:33:12 AM", "10/2/2014 1:13:01 AM", 
"10/2/2014 4:14:15 AM", "10/2/2014 4:23:31 AM", "10/2/2014 4:28:21 AM", 
"10/2/2014 10:00:06 PM", "10/2/2014 10:46:58 PM", "10/2/2014 11:10:36 PM", 
"10/3/2014 12:28:55 AM", "10/3/2014 12:55:06 AM", "10/3/2014 1:10:36 AM", 
"10/3/2014 1:20:41 AM", "10/3/2014 1:30:41 AM", "10/3/2014 1:35:02 AM", 
"10/3/2014 1:42:02 AM", "10/3/2014 2:05:05 AM", "10/3/2014 2:12:30 AM", 
"10/3/2014 2:17:05 AM", "10/3/2014 2:21:36 AM", "10/3/2014 2:28:01 AM", 
"10/3/2014 2:34:52 AM", "10/3/2014 4:01:03 AM", "10/3/2014 4:05:58 AM", 
"10/3/2014 4:18:34 AM", "10/3/2014 4:28:29 AM", "10/3/2014 4:31:50 AM", 
"10/3/2014 4:35:55 AM", "10/3/2014 6:00:15 AM", "10/3/2014 6:29:57 AM", 
"10/3/2014 6:33:37 AM", "10/3/2014 6:46:58 AM", "10/3/2014 7:02:00 AM", 
"10/3/2014 7:11:36 AM", "10/3/2014 7:18:32 AM", "10/3/2014 7:36:38 AM", 
"10/3/2014 8:04:27 AM", "10/3/2014 9:30:15 AM", "10/3/2014 10:16:38 AM", 
"10/3/2014 11:28:14 AM", "10/3/2014 12:13:46 PM", "10/3/2014 1:08:55 PM", 
"10/3/2014 1:12:10 PM", "10/3/2014 2:28:59 PM", "10/3/2014 2:51:51 PM", 
"10/3/2014 3:13:46 PM", "10/3/2014 3:43:47 PM", "10/3/2014 4:05:47 PM", 
"10/3/2014 5:12:46 PM", "10/3/2014 6:02:10 PM", "10/3/2014 6:25:01 PM", 
"10/3/2014 11:19:32 PM", "10/4/2014 9:16:18 AM", "10/4/2014 11:07:55 AM", 
"10/4/2014 11:59:58 AM", "10/4/2014 12:42:29 PM", "10/4/2014 2:00:54 PM", 
"10/4/2014 2:05:44 PM", "10/4/2014 2:09:39 PM", "10/4/2014 2:31:20 PM", 
"10/4/2014 5:20:04 PM", "10/4/2014 6:23:53 PM", "10/4/2014 6:31:39 PM", 
"10/4/2014 6:35:19 PM", "10/4/2014 6:38:40 PM", "10/4/2014 7:04:09 PM", 
"10/4/2014 7:16:35 PM", "10/5/2014 2:51:50 AM", "10/5/2014 3:08:26 AM", 
"10/5/2014 3:15:06 AM", "10/5/2014 3:46:12 AM", "10/5/2014 3:52:58 AM", 
"10/5/2014 4:00:58 AM", "10/5/2014 4:05:54 AM", "10/5/2014 4:27:50 AM", 
"10/5/2014 5:03:22 AM", "10/5/2014 5:09:42 AM", "10/5/2014 5:24:23 AM", 
"10/5/2014 5:35:29 AM", "10/5/2014 5:39:44 AM", "10/5/2014 6:00:40 AM", 
"10/5/2014 6:10:31 AM", "10/5/2014 6:18:22 AM", "10/5/2014 6:26:11 AM", 
"10/5/2014 6:33:52 AM", "10/5/2014 6:54:43 AM", "10/5/2014 7:11:13 AM", 
"10/5/2014 7:15:43 AM", "10/5/2014 8:08:37 AM", "10/5/2014 9:10:24 AM", 
"10/5/2014 9:13:14 AM", "10/5/2014 9:27:19 AM", "10/5/2014 9:40:26 AM", 
"10/5/2014 10:17:48 AM", "10/5/2014 10:51:59 AM", "10/5/2014 10:55:04 AM"
), total.duration = c(355L, 50L, 611L, 3419L, 861L, 2229L, 431L, 
416L, 155L, 235L, 2642L, 1283L, 4524L, 1360L, 775L, 405L, 20L, 
26L, 190L, 976L, 166L, 136L, 60L, 145L, 41L, 80L, 146L, 380L, 
201L, 41L, 80L, 461L, 752L, 45L, 670L, 85L, 426L, 286L, 935L, 
1256L, 4882L, 2644L, 4111L, 2212L, 256L, 50L, 720L, 1192L, 1085L, 
1515L, 931L, 3759L, 1851L, 1201L, 840L, 2397L, 6528L, 2993L, 
2421L, 3597L, 35L, 35L, 6L, 1327L, 246L, 221L, 65L, 25L, 830L, 
596L, 831L, 310L, 245L, 1696L, 100L, 336L, 85L, 1181L, 1847L, 
170L, 586L, 355L, 45L, 866L, 371L, 310L, 294L, 271L, 245L, 190L, 
26L, 3004L, 3517L, 35L, 706L, 641L, 2112L, 1892L, 6L, 71L), site = structure(c(4L, 
4L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), .Label = c("CLRS", "CVP1", 
"GL1", "IC1", "IC2", "IC3", "ORN1", "ORN2", "ORS1", "ORS3", "RGD1", 
"RGU1", "WC1", "WC2", "WC3"), class = "factor"), number.Of.Pings = c(15L, 
4L, 25L, 513L, 163L, 368L, 27L, 16L, 10L, 14L, 214L, 167L, 566L, 
175L, 146L, 13L, 5L, 7L, 13L, 82L, 17L, 10L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 15L, 
10L, 32L, 10L, 4L, 8L, 47L, 44L, 8L, 75L, 10L, 20L, 31L, 47L, 
266L, 623L, 398L, 480L, 305L, 19L, 10L, 23L, 71L, 90L, 110L, 
108L, 797L, 167L, 105L, 118L, 211L, 773L, 368L, 455L, 729L, 8L, 
11L, 3L, 59L, 20L, 8L, 2L, 5L, 33L, 24L, 68L, 20L, 14L, 118L, 
2L, 19L, 12L, 85L, 117L, 8L, 33L, 13L, 9L, 85L, 42L, 19L, 11L, 
20L, 25L, 10L, 4L, 500L, 703L, 2L, 124L, 101L, 449L, 401L, 4L, 
9L), species = c("Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", "Striped Bass", 
"Striped Bass"), StartDateTime_UTC = structure(c(1412030440, 
1412030955, 1412204472, 1412205378, 1412208947, 1412209992, 1412212381, 
1412223255, 1412223811, 1412224101, 1412287206, 1412290018, 1412291436, 
1412296135, 1412297706, 1412298636, 1412299241, 1412299841, 1412300102, 
1412300522, 1412301905, 1412302350, 1412302625, 1412302896, 1412303281, 
1412303692, 1412308863, 1412309158, 1412309914, 1412310509, 1412310710, 
1412310955, 1412316015, 1412317797, 1412318017, 1412318818, 1412319720, 
1412320296, 1412320712, 1412321798, 1412323467, 1412328615, 1412331398, 
1412335694, 1412338426, 1412341735, 1412341930, 1412346539, 1412347911, 
1412349226, 1412351027, 1412352347, 1412356366, 1412359330, 1412360701, 
1412378372, 1412414178, 1412420875, 1412423998, 1412426549, 1412431254, 
1412431544, 1412431779, 1412433080, 1412443204, 1412447033, 1412447499, 
1412447719, 1412447920, 1412449449, 1412450195, 1412477510, 1412478506, 
1412478906, 1412480772, 1412481178, 1412481658, 1412481954, 1412483270, 
1412485402, 1412485782, 1412486663, 1412487329, 1412487584, 1412488840, 
1412489431, 1412489902, 1412490371, 1412490832, 1412492083, 1412493073, 
1412493343, 1412496517, 1412500224, 1412500394, 1412501239, 1412502026, 
1412504268, 1412506319, 1412506504), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Duration_sec = new("Period", .Data = c(355, 
50, 611, 3419, 861, 2229, 431, 416, 155, 235, 2642, 1283, 4524, 
1360, 775, 405, 20, 26, 190, 976, 166, 136, 60, 145, 41, 80, 
146, 380, 201, 41, 80, 461, 752, 45, 670, 85, 426, 286, 935, 
1256, 4882, 2644, 4111, 2212, 256, 50, 720, 1192, 1085, 1515, 
931, 3759, 1851, 1201, 840, 2397, 6528, 2993, 2421, 3597, 35, 
35, 6, 1327, 246, 221, 65, 25, 830, 596, 831, 310, 245, 1696, 
100, 336, 85, 1181, 1847, 170, 586, 355, 45, 866, 371, 310, 294, 
271, 245, 190, 26, 3004, 3517, 35, 706, 641, 2112, 1892, 6, 71
), year = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    month = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), day = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), hour = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), minute = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), EndDateTime_UTC = structure(c(1412030795, 
1412031005, 1412205083, 1412208797, 1412209808, 1412212221, 1412212812, 
1412223671, 1412223966, 1412224336, 1412289848, 1412291301, 1412295960, 
1412297495, 1412298481, 1412299041, 1412299261, 1412299867, 1412300292, 
1412301498, 1412302071, 1412302486, 1412302685, 1412303041, 1412303322, 
1412303772, 1412309009, 1412309538, 1412310115, 1412310550, 1412310790, 
1412311416, 1412316767, 1412317842, 1412318687, 1412318903, 1412320146, 
1412320582, 1412321647, 1412323054, 1412328349, 1412331259, 1412335509, 
1412337906, 1412338682, 1412341785, 1412342650, 1412347731, 1412348996, 
1412350741, 1412351958, 1412356106, 1412358217, 1412360531, 1412361541, 
1412380769, 1412420706, 1412423868, 1412426419, 1412430146, 1412431289, 
1412431579, 1412431785, 1412434407, 1412443450, 1412447254, 1412447564, 
1412447744, 1412448750, 1412450045, 1412451026, 1412477820, 1412478751, 
1412480602, 1412480872, 1412481514, 1412481743, 1412483135, 1412485117, 
1412485572, 1412486368, 1412487018, 1412487374, 1412488450, 1412489211, 
1412489741, 1412490196, 1412490642, 1412491077, 1412492273, 1412493099, 
1412496347, 1412500034, 1412500259, 1412501100, 1412501880, 1412504138, 
1412506160, 1412506325, 1412506575), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), StartOpen = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), EndOpen = c(FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
), location = c("IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", 
"IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", 
"IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", 
"IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", 
"IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", 
"IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", 
"IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", 
"IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", 
"IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", "IN", 
"IN", "IN", "IN", "IN")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Gate Closed Intervals

```
new("Interval", .Data = c(-81060, -117060, -59400, -16200, -76680, 
-51000, -81120), start = structure(c(1412238660, 1412362800, 
1412434800, 1412454600, 1412542980, 1412602200, 1412690400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), tzone = "UTC")
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you are looking for as output (can be dummy data), but format would be helpful.  I also get an error "Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
  “Period” is not a defined class" when I run your example data code.  Perhaps strip it down to make it a little more minimal

Comment: It sounds like you may be able to use a database join approach to connect the observation data with the interval data. This assumes they're in two separate tables.

Comment: @BrianFisher I've updated the question and fixed the dput for the gate_closed periods

Comment: I think you should be able to use something like `which(Detections$StartDateTime_UTC %in% Interval)` to get an index you can then convert to an ID.  I can't test it though, because the two sets of data you provided don't overlap ( the intervals are all in March/April 2013, while the detections are all in Sept/Oct 2014)

Comment: @BrianFisher that's what I get for trying to subset the data. Unfortunately that just returns integer 0.  I'll try to get the right intervals for that individual

Comment: updated with intervals which should overlap the data used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there are some problems with your example data that made answering your question difficult.

1. Your example detection data includes a lot of extra information not needed to address or understand your question.
2. Your example intervals are backwards.  (They end before they start)
3. Your example data is not set up in a format that is easy to use (you don't include the packages needed to read it).

That said, let's simplify and correct these issues:

```
library(tidyverse)  # needed because your data is in tibble format
library(lubridate)  # needed for time interval class used in your example

# I called your example data "Detections" and "Intervals", not importing them here

set.seed(914)
row.sample <- c(1,5,2, sample(1:100, 10)) # to include the samples not in the given intervals mixed with good values
use.cols <- c(1,4,6,7,9)  
Detections.use <- Detections[row.sample, use.cols]

Detections.use
# A tibble: 13 x 5
   Tag     site  species      StartDateTime_UTC   EndDateTime_UTC    
   <fct>   <fct> <chr>        <dttm>              <dttm>             
 1 5004.24 IC1   Striped Bass 2014-09-29 22:40:40 2014-09-29 22:46:35
 2 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 00:15:47 2014-10-02 00:30:08
 3 5004.24 IC1   Striped Bass 2014-09-29 22:49:15 2014-09-29 22:50:05
 4 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-04 18:38:40 2014-10-04 18:52:30
 5 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-05 07:15:43 2014-10-05 08:05:47
 6 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 02:21:36 2014-10-03 02:24:01
 7 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 12:13:46 2014-10-03 12:18:02
 8 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 09:30:15 2014-10-03 10:14:19
 9 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-04 14:09:39 2014-10-04 14:09:45
10 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 02:17:05 2014-10-03 02:18:05
11 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-05 03:08:26 2014-10-05 03:12:31
12 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 01:42:02 2014-10-03 01:58:18
13 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 00:33:12 2014-10-02 01:10:21


# Convert your intervals to a table, then correct them to make them positive time intevals
Interval.table <- tibble(Intervals, "ID" = seq(from = 1, to = length(Intervals))) %>%
      mutate(end_time = Intervals$start,
             start_time = end_time+Intervals$.Data,
             new_Interval = start_time %--% end_time) %>%
      select(ID, new_Interval)
Interval.table
# A tibble: 7 x 2
     ID new_Interval                                    
  <int> <Interval>                                      
1     1 2014-10-01 10:00:00 UTC--2014-10-02 08:31:00 UTC
2     2 2014-10-02 10:29:00 UTC--2014-10-03 19:00:00 UTC
3     3 2014-10-03 22:30:00 UTC--2014-10-04 15:00:00 UTC
4     4 2014-10-04 16:00:00 UTC--2014-10-04 20:30:00 UTC
5     5 2014-10-04 23:45:00 UTC--2014-10-05 21:03:00 UTC
6     6 2014-10-05 23:20:00 UTC--2014-10-06 13:30:00 UTC
7     7 2014-10-06 15:28:00 UTC--2014-10-07 14:00:00 UTC
```

Now to address your question
The lubridate package includes a function `%within%` that test if a time is within a time interval, but strangely for tidyverse functions, it doesn't seem to vectorize very well.   I wasn't able to figure out how to get this to work within the typical dplyr/tidyr syntax, but using a for loop, we can make a vector containing the ID of which interval each time fits into and NA for the ones that are not within any of the given interals.

```
y <- c()
for (i in 1:length(Detections.use$StartDateTime_UTC)){
z<- which(Detections.use$StartDateTime_UTC[i] %within% Interval.table$new_Interval)
y[i] <- ifelse(isTRUE(z>0), z, NA)
}
Detections.use$Interval <- y
Detections.use
# A tibble: 13 x 6
   Tag     site  species      StartDateTime_UTC   EndDateTime_UTC     Interval
   <fct>   <fct> <chr>        <dttm>              <dttm>                 <int>
 1 5004.24 IC1   Striped Bass 2014-09-29 22:40:40 2014-09-29 22:46:35       NA
 2 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 00:15:47 2014-10-02 00:30:08        1
 3 5004.24 IC1   Striped Bass 2014-09-29 22:49:15 2014-09-29 22:50:05       NA
 4 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-04 18:38:40 2014-10-04 18:52:30        4
 5 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-05 07:15:43 2014-10-05 08:05:47        5
 6 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 02:21:36 2014-10-03 02:24:01        2
 7 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 12:13:46 2014-10-03 12:18:02        2
 8 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 09:30:15 2014-10-03 10:14:19        2
 9 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-04 14:09:39 2014-10-04 14:09:45        3
10 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 02:17:05 2014-10-03 02:18:05        2
11 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-05 03:08:26 2014-10-05 03:12:31        5
12 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-03 01:42:02 2014-10-03 01:58:18        2
13 5004.24 RGD1  Striped Bass 2014-10-02 00:33:12 2014-10-02 01:10:21        1
```

Edited to add `sapply` solution ---

This could also be done with `sapply` a little smoother, and without leaving the artifacts:

```
which.join <- function(x, y) {
      z <- which(x %within% y)
      z <- ifelse(isTRUE(z > 0), z, NA)
      z
}

Detections.use$Interval <- sapply(Detections.use$StartDateTime_UTC, 
                             function(x) which.join(x,Interval.table$new_Interval)
```

Another approach may be using the fuzzyjoin package as shown [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/tidy-way-to-range-join-tables-on-an-interval-of-dates/7881)

Comment: this is fairly close to the answer I came up with:
`for (i in 1:length(dat_overlap$StartDateTime_UTC)) {
  tryCatch({
    dat_overlap$interval.id[i] <- which(dat_overlap$StartDateTime_UTC[i] %within% ops_tib)
  }, error = function(e){})
  }`


I apologise for my formatting and question.  I'm still relatively new to communicating in stack overflow.  I'll work on paring down my data sets to make them more direct and add in my packages.